# Change Salesforce Error Messages?

Tags: apex, error, exception, visualforce

Currently when Apex code on a VisualForce page throws an exception the user is shown what line of code threw the exception and some other information.  I want to change this to show a custom error message, something along the lines of "Something went wrong, please contact Software Development at softwaredevelopment@company.com."

Answer (score 1):

Have you ever tried exception handling via Try-Catch block?

Put your code inside a try block and catch block with catch the exception if any exception occurs. You can add the custom exception message to apexPages variable

```
try{
    //Your code goes here
}Catch(Exception e){
    ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,'Your custom message'));
    //You can also access exception string by e.getMessage() method
}
```

More details about exception class - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_exception_methods.htm

Modify your VF Page to include a  tag and it will display the error when added by your apex class.

Comment: yep - totally agree --  and if I were in "Software Development" @ company.com, and this was an otherwise unexpected, albeit caught, exception, I'd like the ApexPages.Message to include the value of `e.getStackTraceString()` so I might be able to diagnose/fix the problem faster rather than having to force the user to reproduce the problem with debug logs on.